# Does it return new object?

Tags: c++, return-value

This code -

```
class myClass{
.....
.....
   myClass operator+(myClass& sc)
   {
      *this += sc;
      return *this;
   }
....
}
```

and this code -

```
class myClass{
.....
.....
   myClass operator+(myClass& sc)
   {
      myClass mc;
      mc += (*this);
      mc += sc;
      return mc;
   }
....
}
```

do they produce same result? In other words, they both return new object. The first one implicitly creates new myClass object and returns it and the other one is explicit. Is it my understanding wrong?

Comment: Both are wrong. Member `operator+` should be `const`. The normal version is `operator+(MyClass const& rhs) const { MyClass copy(*this); copy += rhs; return copy; }`

Comment: @MSalters +1. Only `+=` operator should modify the `this` object.

Comment: To clarify: You couldn't write `a+b+c` for the either of the definitions given, precisely because they miss `const`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both return new objects, and both return objects with (presumably) identical values, but the first one modifies `this`, before making a copy.

Answer (score 0):

yes.  return value is "myClass". if you want to avoid copy of object: change it on myClass& or myClass* (reference or poiter), but do not return pointer/reference on temporary object..